# Facebook image sharing working in emulator but not in device

Tags: android

Now I am working on a Android application. In my app i have to submit a image from my gallery to facebook.I used the following code.

```
if (item == 1) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();

                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete      action using"), PICK_FROM_FILE);
}


protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
 {
        if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) return;

        Bitmap bitmap   = null;

        if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_FILE) {

            mImageCaptureUri = data.getData(); 

            mPath = getRealPathFromURI(mImageCaptureUri); //from Gallery 

            if (mPath == null){
                    mPath = mImageCaptureUri.getPath(); //from File Manager
            }


            if (mPath != null) {
                System.out.println("mpath is not null"+mPath);
                bitmap  = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mPath);
            }

        }
}
private void postToFacebook(String desc){   

    AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncFbRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(mFacebook);

    Bundle params = new Bundle();

     try {

        params.putByteArray("photo",
        Utility.scaleImage(getApplicationContext(),mImageCaptureUri));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
     params.putString("caption", desc);
     mAsyncFbRunner.request("me/photos", params, "POST",
             new PhotoUploadListener());
}
```

Its working fine for me in emulater but in real device image is not posting.But no crash.Please help me friends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chk your manifest first, may this will help you.

```
android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS
```